How to center output plots in Jupyter Lab (not Jupyter Notebook!)
How do we center output plots (e.g. plotly plots) in Jupyter Lab? All the solutions I've seen are for Jupyter Notebooks and say to do something like this:
HTML("""
<style>
.jp-RenderedImage {
    display: table-cell;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
</style>
""")

But that doesn't work in Jupyter Lab (version 3.6.7).

I doubt that will work in current Jupyter Notebook either. By current, I mean Jupyter Notebook 7+. Accessing internals that way was always a bit of a hack and now that in Jupyter Notebook 7+, things are using the same components as current JupyterLab, those hacks also don't work in Jupyter Notebook version 7+. Usually you now need to see what the method is for JupyterLab, whether you are in JupyterLab or Jupyter Notebook 7+. That was just to clarify some things so you know a little more about why what things may work where or how to search better for updated information.

That all being said, I don't know the answer to this one. Or I am not recalling it yet. One thing to so is just adjust the padding on the left side of your plot so it comes out more to the right. This was always a better way because it didn't involve needing the code for that hack you reference. In other words, you could be sure it would looked similar if your code was being run in classic Jupyter Notebook or JupyterLab. For now, I'll need to look into this when I have more time. Maye someone else will come along with a better idea and I'll delete this comment later.
